# Rails: notifications using GetStream and Acts As Follower gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, getstream-io

I'm using [getstream](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-rails) and [acts as follower](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower) to build a notification and news feed for my project. When following a certain user, that user is supposed to get a notification of such following. I'm able to follow and unfollow users, but getstream gives the following error:

```
Something went wrong creating an activity: undefined local variable or method `user' for #<Follow:0x007ffaa70c9398>
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 37ms

NameError (undefined local variable or method `user' for #<Follow:0x007ffaa70c9398>):
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:160:in `follow_user'


Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (3.1ms)
Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (0.8ms)
Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb (0.9ms)
Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.text.erb (108.1ms)
```

This if what my `follow.rb` file looks like:

```
class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base

  extend ActsAsFollower::FollowerLib
  extend ActsAsFollower::FollowScopes

  # NOTE: Follows belong to the "followable" interface, and also to followers
  belongs_to :followable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :follower,   :polymorphic => true


  include StreamRails::Activity
  as_activity

  def activity_notify
    [StreamRails.feed_manager.get_notification_feed(self.followable_id)]
  end

  def activity_object
    self.followable
  end

  def block!
    self.update_attribute(:blocked, true)
  end

end
```

And in `user.rb` I have:

```
acts_as_followable
acts_as_follower
```

and nothing else referencing the `Follow` model. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong ?

EDIT:

Here is my follow and unfollow code in the users controller. Line 160 is `if @follower.follow(@following)`, and likewise for unfollowing:

```
def follow_user
  @follower = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
  @following = User.where(id: params[:following_id]).first
  @user = @following

  if @follower == @following
    respond_to do |format|
      flash.now[:warning] = "Cannot follow yourself."
      format.js {  render file: "/app/views/layouts/notice.js.erb" }
    end
  end

  if @follower.follow(@following)
    StreamRails.feed_manager.follow_user(@follower.id, @following.id)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render file: "/app/views/users/follow.js.erb" }
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      flash.now[:info] = "Error."
      format.js {  render file: "/app/views/layouts/notice.js.erb" }
    end
  end
end

def unfollow_user
  @follower = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
  @following = User.find(params[:following_id])
  @user = @following

  if @follower.stop_following(@following)  
    StreamRails.feed_manager.unfollow_user(@follower.id, @following.id)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render file: "/app/views/users/follow.js.erb" }
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      flash.now[:info] = "Error."
      format.js { render file: "/app/views/users/add_flag.js.erb" }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi, can I have a look at your users_controller?

Comment: @pyfl88 Added the code for follow and unfollow

Answer (score 0):

The [stream-rails](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-rails) gem assumes that your model has a `user` attribute to lookup the actor of the activity. You can change this behavior by implementing the `activity_actor` method in your `Follow` model.

For example:

```
class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base

    def activity_actor
        self.follower
    end

end
```

This will create activities such as "x followed y" when a follow model is created (as well as the logic that you already have implemented to create actual follow connections between feeds).